# Enabling & Disabling Buttons

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qpushbutton

I am developing an application in Python and I want to have a specific set of buttons set to disabled until another button is clicked first. For Example, When I press the Sim Card button, I want the Sim Report button to be set to enabled.

I have tried to implement the functionality using this solution: [How to make push button immediately disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33954886/how-to-make-push-button-immediately-disabled) but it only disables the button for 5 seconds. I want to only enable a specific button when a condition has been met in a corresponding button. I do not want to generate a report unless the data has been parsed first basically.

```
# import Statements
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QWidget
from reportViewerWindow import Ui_reportViewerWindow
import os

# Main Class that holds User Interface Objects
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    # Function for Opening Report Viewer Window From Main Window by clicking View Reports button
    def openReportViewer(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_reportViewerWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()



    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(834, 428)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: Cornflowerblue")
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        # Sim Card Button
        self.simCardButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.simCardButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 200, 211, 30))
        self.simCardButton.setToolTip("Select to parse sim card data")
        self.simCardButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.simCardButton.setFont(font)
        self.simCardButton.setObjectName("simCardButton")


        # Call Logs Button
        self.callLogButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.callLogButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 300, 211, 30))
        self.callLogButton.setToolTip("Select to parse call log data")
        self.callLogButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.callLogButton.setFont(font)
        self.callLogButton.setObjectName("callLogButton")


        # SMS Button
        self.smsButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.smsButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 250, 211, 30))
        self.smsButton.setToolTip("Select to parse sms data")
        self.smsButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smsButton.setFont(font)
        self.smsButton.setObjectName("smsButton")


        # Canonical Address Button
        self.canonicalAddressesButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 150, 211, 30))
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setToolTip("Select to parse canonical address data")
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setFont(font)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setObjectName("canonicalAddressesButton")


        # Main Window Label
        self.windowMainLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.windowMainLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 20, 423, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.windowMainLabel.setFont(font)
        self.windowMainLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.windowMainLabel.setObjectName("windowMainLabel")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 291, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")


        # # View Reports Button
        self.viewReportsButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.viewReportsButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.viewReportsButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 370, 175, 31))
        self.viewReportsButton.clicked.connect(self.openReportViewer)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.viewReportsButton.setFont(font)
        self.viewReportsButton.setObjectName("viewReportsButton")
        self.viewReportsButton.setEnabled(False)


        # Label for evidence viewer
        self.evidenceViewingLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 120, 141, 16))
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setObjectName("evidenceViewingLabel")

        # Buttons for report generation
        self.generate_canonical_report = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generate_canonical_report.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 150, 175, 31))
        self.generate_canonical_report.setObjectName("generate_canonical_report")
        self.generate_canonical_report.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.generate_canonical_report.setEnabled(False)


        self.generate_Sim_Report = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 190, 175, 31))
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setObjectName("generate_sim_report")
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setEnabled(False)


        self.generateSMS_Report = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generateSMS_Report.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 230, 175, 31))
        self.generateSMS_Report.setObjectName("generate_sms_report")
        self.generateSMS_Report.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.generateSMS_Report.setEnabled(False)


        self.generate_callLog_report = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generate_callLog_report.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 270, 175, 31))
        self.generate_callLog_report.setObjectName("generate_callLog_report")
        self.generate_callLog_report.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.generate_callLog_report.setEnabled(False)


        self.generateFullReportButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generateFullReportButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 310, 175, 31))
        self.generateFullReportButton.setObjectName("generateFullReportButton")
        self.generateFullReportButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: Silver")
        self.generateFullReportButton.setEnabled(False)



        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.actionOpen_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_2.setObjectName("actionOpen_2")
        self.actionExit_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit_2.setObjectName("actionExit_2")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    # Function that sets the text on all the UI Buttons
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "DB Parser"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Data Parsing Options"))
        self.simCardButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sim Card"))
        self.callLogButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Call Logs"))
        self.smsButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SMS "))
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Canonical Addresses"))
        self.windowMainLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Python Mobile Device Parser"))

        # Report Button set text and tool_tips
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Report Generator"))

        self.generate_canonical_report.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Canonical Report"))
        self.generate_canonical_report.setToolTip("Select to generate canonical address report")

        self.generate_Sim_Report.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sim Report"))
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setToolTip("Select to generate sim card report")

        self.generateSMS_Report.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SMS Report"))
        self.generateSMS_Report.setToolTip("Select to generate sms report")

        self.generate_callLog_report.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Call Log Report"))
        self.generate_callLog_report.setToolTip("Select to generate call log report")

        self.viewReportsButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "View Reports"))
        self.viewReportsButton.setToolTip("Select to open report viewing window")

        self.generateFullReportButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Full Report"))
        self.generateFullReportButton.setToolTip("Select to generate full report")

        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.actionOpen_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionExit_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))

    # Event Handling Code Section


        # Parsing Area!!!

        # Canonical Addresses Button click functionality to parse canonical address data
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.select_canonical_data)

        # Sim Card Button click functionality to parse sim card data
        self.simCardButton.clicked.connect(self.select_sim_data)

        # Call Logs Button click functionality to parse call log data
        self.callLogButton.clicked.connect(self.select_call_data)

        # SMS Button click functionality to parse SMS data
        self.smsButton.clicked.connect(self.select_sms_data)

        # Reporting Area!!!

        # canonical address report generating functionality
        self.generate_canonical_report.clicked.connect(self.generate_canonicalR)

        # sim card report generating functionality
        self.generate_Sim_Report.clicked.connect(self.generate_simR)

        # sms report generating functionality
        self.generateSMS_Report.clicked.connect(self.generate_smsR)

        # call log report generating functionality
        self.generate_callLog_report.clicked.connect(self.generate_call_LogR)

        # All data report
        self.generateFullReportButton.clicked.connect(self.generate_full_reportR)


        # Report Generation Functions!!!
        self.one_pass = True
        self.two_pass = False
        self.three_pass = False
        self.four_pass = False

    # Data Parsing Functions!!!

    # Canonical Addresses button function
    def select_canonical_data(self):
        os.system('CanonicalAddressesParser.py')
        self.generate_canonical_report.setEnabled(True)

    # call log button function
    def select_call_data(self):
        os.system('CallLogParser.py')
        self.generate_callLog_report.setEnabled(True)

    # sms button function
    def select_sms_data(self):
        os.system('SmsParser.py')
        self.generateSMS_Report.setEnabled(True)

    # sim card button function
    def select_sim_data(self):
        os.system('SimCardParser.py')
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setEnabled(True)


    def generate_canonicalR(self):
        os.system('CanonicalAddressReporter.py')
        self.generate_canonical_report.setEnabled(True)
        self.check_run_button()


    def generate_call_LogR(self):
        os.system('CallLogReporter.py')
        self.generate_callLog_report.setEnabled(True)
        self.check_run_button()


    def generate_smsR(self):
        os.system('SmsDataReporter.py')
        self.generateSMS_Report.setEnabled(True)
        self.check_run_button()

    def generate_simR(self):
        os.system('SimCardReporter.py')
        self.generate_Sim_Report.setEnabled(True)
        self.check_run_button()



    def generate_full_reportR(self):
        os.system('AllDataReport.py')
        self.check_run_button()

    def check_run_button(self):
        if self.one_pass == self.two_pass == self.three_pass == self.four_pass is True:
            self.generateFullReportButton.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enable and disable buttons by using `button.setEnabled(False)` or `button.setEnabled(True)`.  As for when they are enabled, just add in the two lines above in the appropriate places to trigger the buttons.

So with your example for instance, start with simReport button disabled.  Then in your `select_sim_data` function, add `generate_Sim_Report.setEnabled(True)`.  You can implement this functionality in any methods that need to control whether a button is enabled.

Comment: Do I not need to use an if statement to check if one button was pressed before it enables the other button?

Comment: Not if you put the button enabler in the function that is called from clicking the other button.  That function will only be run when the corresponding button is clicked.  If you need to check for other variables in the code, if/else statements can be used.

Comment: Ok I will try to implement this.

Comment: It has worked well. Thank You. How can I set the FullReport button to disabled until Canonical Report, Sim Report, SMS Report and Call Log Report buttons are true. I cannot generate a full report until all these other report buttons above it have been executed first. I have set the generateFullReportButton to false and I need it to be enabled once all other buttons are clicked. I have tried to run an if statement to check if the first 4 buttons are true. I have edited the code above with my attempted if statement.

Comment: The if statement that you added is not formatted correctly and will not work.  It is also unreachable.  To check all conditions are true, you can make bool variables for each button, set them to true when the button is clicked, and each time a button is clicked, check if each variable is true and if so enable the button.

Comment: I have tried to implement what you suggested but it wont enable the button. I have updated the code to show what I have been trying to do with flags.

Comment: What you implemented was not what I suggested.  You are only checking values that you just set to True in the previous line.  Of course they are true.  In none of those methods are you checking to see if each variable is true and then setting the FullReport button enabled.

Comment: The issue is though is that, what if i did set FullReportButton to True in one of the methods and then someone hits that button before another one of the buttons is hit. This then means that the FullReportButton has been enabled before all 4 single reporting buttons have been selected. This throws an error as the full report needs all individual data to be available before generating the full report. So how can I set the FullReportButton to True only when all other single report buttons are clicked.

Comment: I have managed to get it working the way I intended it to and I understand what the code is doing now. Thank again for your help my apologies for your trouble.

Comment: PyQt6 -> .setEnabled(True) and .setDisabled(True) works as expected