# QLineEdit color change for a flash when return pressed in PySide

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I am having a QLineEdit object and the inbuilt signal 'returnPressed' is connected to perform some task. But when I click return, I want to notify the user about the key press by flashing a different color for a small duration and reverse back to the original color. Although, this could be done by changing background color through set style sheets and time.sleep() function but I want a direct one line approach to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't think there is a one-line solution to this. But what's wrong with setting the style sheet and setting it back after some time?  The only important thing is: **Do not use `time.sleep()` inside your application.** Instead, you may use `QTimer`.

Comment: self.lineEdit_CycleTime.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(5, 8, 5)")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    self.lineEdit_CycleTime.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(125, 125,        125)")

Comment: Please suggest use of QTimer in place of time.sleep() for the above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, you need to avoid using `time.sleep()`. Instead, you can use a `QTimer`. The `QTimer`'s static `singleShot` method can call a function after waiting 500 ms. The function you'd call in this case can be lambda function, which sets the style sheet.

```
self.lineEdit_CycleTime.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(5, 8, 5)")
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(500, lambda :self.lineEdit_CycleTime.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(125,125,125)") )
```

Comment: Hi, It works smoothly. Thanks a lot. Just wanted to know why time.sleep() is a bad idea to use here instead of QTimer.singleshot().

Comment: `time.sleep()` causes the program to literally sleep. While this is totally  acceptable in a console application, it will cause trouble in Graphical user interfaces. GUIs need to stay responsive all the time for the user to act in them (moving the mouse, placing cursor) and to listen to events. If the program sleeps it cannot perform those tasks and a non-responsive program is usually reported as crashed by the window management system. (see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801007/sleep-is-not-working-on-pyqt4))